# Trigger an email send from changes in a DE without Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

We are working with a client who did NOT purchase JB (they only have Automation Studio) but want to configure an email send from changes registered to either a DE or an Object in SFDC (we have integration with Sales/Service Cloud).

A SFMC Executive mentioned it would be possible to trigger an email from changes in data in a Synchronized Data Extension or Standard DE (never said how).

For example: a customer changed their initial preference, and they want the system to send a new email to the customer as soon as the change is registered.

I proposed the following solution:

1. Create a filter or Query to extract contacts that have a "Modified
   date" of "Today"
2. Automate the execution of said filter via Automation Studio
3. Next step in Automation would be Send Email
4. Automation would run Hourly

But the customer wants the email to be send almost instantly.

Are there other methods of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client is wanting the email to deploy near real time and the client did not purchase Journey Builder, then you will need to use Triggered Sends.

If the Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud ORG are integrated, which it sounds like they are, then you can leverage the MC Connector to do this.  Refer to the following online documentation.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_triggered_sends.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks a lot @David, this is precisely one of the proposed solutions we offered the client.
Perhaps they didnt understand it correctly...I will go back to then and explain it in detail. Thanks again.